# Upload files using perl module jQuery::File::Upload

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, file-upload

I'm trying to use [Sebastian Tschan's perfect upload scripts](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) with the [Perl handler](http://search.cpan.org/~srchulo/jQuery-File-Upload-0.05/lib/jQuery/File/Upload.pm).

The script seems to work well but no file is uploaded. There is no error message in either the console or the error log.

I try to use the basic version. Here is what I've done.

#### Inside `basic.html` I set

```
var url = window.location.hostname === 'http://myserver/upload-images/upload.pl';
```

#### `main.js` line 21

```
  url: 'http://myserver/upload-images/upload.pl'
```

#### `upload.pl` looks like this

```
#!C:\Strawberry\PERL\BIN\perl.exe

use jQuery::File::Upload;

# simplest implementation
my $j_fu = jQuery::File::Upload->new;
$j_fu->handle_request;
$j_fu->print_response;
```

The result is the same when I set

```
$j_fu->upload_dir('C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/htdocs/upload-images/files');
$j_fu->upload_url_base('http://myserver/upload-images/files');
```

I have an Apache server on Windows, and I thought it could be a permissions problem or something like that. But when I try to use the same method on my production server (setting `chmod 777` on the `files` directory) I have the same problem. No file is uploaded and there is no error message at all.

`jQuery::File::Upload` is properly installed, as well as `Image::Magick` on both servers.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: First order of business when troubleshooting web apps that appear to do nothing is to open your browser's developer tools and check that a request is actually being made, the correct parameters are being sent, and the expected response comes back. That will help you find the broken link in the chain.

Comment: The console says `jquery.js:9664 XHR finished loading: POST "http://myserver/upload-images/basic.html"`, no error !

Comment: What was the response code? Does the request body actually include the file contents? What was the value of the Content-Type header in the request? Is there anything in the response body? This info should all be available in the network tab of the dev tools.

Comment: Response code is 200. Inside the "post" panel, I can see that the file (actually a png file) is well sent to the server. The response body contains the whole content of `basic.html`. I cannot find the Content-Type header in the dev tool of Chrome and Firefox...

Comment: Wait, why are you posting to an HTML page? The request should be going to a Perl script that can process it.

Comment: No, I'm not posting to the HTML page but to upload.pl. The full code of basic.html is here http://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/basic.html and I only changed lines 114 and 115 to point to the perl handler like mentionned above.

Comment: The `POST "http://myserver/upload-images/basic.html"` in your first comment makes it seem like you are posting to an HTML page. When you look at the request in the dev tools, what URL is it going to?

Comment: Yes I guess because it's ajax and you can notice in the whole `basic.html` code that `upload.pl` is the final destination (js part). By the way, I also tried to insert `data-url="http://myserver/upload-images/upload.pl"` inside the <input> tag and to apply the minimal setup guide here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin but no file is uploaded ! If I switch to the php handler, everything is ok, but I'd like to use Perl !! Everything I found on the net is useless regarding this module. I'm wondering if only 1 person is using it with success... ?